# "Show In-App Purchases" Not Showing In App Store

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I have an app on the App Store that has In-App Purchases, but on the store there isn't a button that says "In-App Purchases" where a user can see what the IAP are.

[image]

Where on mine (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/uidesign-draw-your-concept/id725323019?mt=8) says it Offers IAP but there isn't a button at the bottom that shows what the IAP are.

[image]

How do I make it available for users to see what IAP i have in my app.

Comment: Hey @DocAsh59 I see you got this working for your app. Any chance you could update this question with an answer telling us how you got it working? :)

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Hello, I do not know, I think it may of taken a bit of time to appear on the App Store. As when I posted this question it was about a day or so it was accepted onto the App Store. So I think just wait a bit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having same problem for my new app - submitted a question to apple support - they replied:

> The In-App Purchases section of your app’s product page will contain
>   the top In-App Purchases for the app only after a minimum purchase
>   requisite has been reached. If the number of completed In-App
>   Purchases doesn’t exceed the minimum threshold, this area will not
>   appear.

Answer (score 1):

It is now showing my In-App Purchases on the App Store.
It just takes a couple days or so to appear on the App Store.